# How to adequately debug code that requires project to be visible to an external API?

Tags: api, git, ftp

So I have an API and it requires my project to be visible on my remote server so that it can communicate with it. (It can't communicate with it on localhost) but of course it's usually preferable to develop projects locally. What I do is develop locally and push changes to a git repo which I then pull from the remote server in ssh. It's a pretty standard vanilla js (es6) and PHP project. My question is, what is a good way to write/debug a project like this because it wouldn't be good to make a change, push to repo, pull from remote server, see if it works, repeat over and over again or make changes directly through FTP which I feel is just in bad taste, what's the best way to do this?